# How to click a button using VBScript in an HTA file

Tags: html, vba, vbscript, forms, hta

My code looks like

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My HTML application</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
    id="frames" 
    border="thin" 
    caption="yes" 
    icon="http://www.google.com/favicon.ico" 
    showintaskbar="yes" 
    singleinstance="yes" 
    sysmenu="yes" 
    navigable="yes" 
    contextmenu="no" 
    innerborder="no" 
    scroll="auto" 
    scrollflat="yes" 
    selection="yes" 
    windowstate="normal" />
</head>

<script language="VBScript">

Sub Window_OnLoad
  'This method will be called when the application loads
  'Add your code here
  GetUserName
End Sub

Sub GetUserName() 
    Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    linkTo("http://servername/nph-psf.exe?HOSTID=AD&ALIAS=" & objNetwork.UserName)
    Set objNetwork = Nothing 
End Sub

Sub linkTo(strLink) 
    Document.getElementById("psyncLink").src = strLink
End Sub

Sub checkInputPage
    Document.theforms.name
End Sub

</script>        
    </head> 
    <frameset rows="60px, *"> 
        <frame src="topo.htm" name="topo" id="topo" application="yes" /> 
        <frame src="http://servername/nph-psf.exe?HOSTID=AD&ALIAS=" name="conteudo" id="psyncLink" application="yes" /> 
    </frameset> 
</html>
```

and the page loads with 2 buttons, how do I perform the click operation programatically?

```
<INPUT border=0 type=image alt="Use a password" name="SUBMIT-password.pss" src="docs/pics/en-us/useapassword_button.jpg">
```

Please note that I can not change any code thats loaded from 
because I do not have write privs to that directory. I am creating an HTA script that can programatically click buttons and links on that page to assist our users with changing their password

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937398/how-to-click-a-button-using-vbscript-in-an-hta-file

This does exactly what I needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [How to click a button using VBScript in an HTA file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937398/how-to-click-a-button-using-vbscript-in-an-hta-file)

This does exactly what I needed

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function doClick(fr) { 
    var btn = fr.contentWindow.document.getElementsByName("SUBMIT-password.pss"); 
    if (btn.length == 0) { 
        alert("no button!"); 
        return; 
    } else { 
        btn[0].click(); 
    } 
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Only an example

```
<INPUT border=0 type=image alt="Use a password" name="cmdBtn" src="docs/pics/en-us/useapassword_button.jpg" onclick="cmdBtn_Click">
```

**VB SCRIPT**

```
<script language="vbscript">
   sub cmdBtn_Click()
       msgbox("Clicked !") 
   end sub
</script>
```

**OR**

```
<INPUT type="Button" value="Click Me" name="cmdBtn" />
```

**VBSCRIPT**

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" EVENT="OnClick" FOR="cmdBtn">
    msgbox("Clicked !")
</script>
```

If you click the button then it will show an alert with text 'Clicked !' in it.

Comment: how do I perform the click operation programatically.

Comment: I can't change the HTML on the page that I am loading. I do not have access to change <input ... to your suggestion.

Comment: You can use second example by using the input name `<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" EVENT="OnClick" FOR="cmdBtn">`

Comment: How does that code cause the button to be clicked programatically? It looks like the user has to click the button and it raises an event handler and then executes code

Comment: Oh ! I really didn't get the point, may be he could have mentioned he wants to trigger an event but anyways, you solved it. It was a misunderstanding. Thanks. +1.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sub cmdBtn_onlick()`?